# july 2013 breaking changes - object create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook app with a single custom action (*earn*) and a single custom object (*badge*). I create these objects for user from my server via POST to

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/' + fb_user_id + '/itsbeta:earn'
```

and send parameters

```
access_token => user_access_token,
badge => badge.fb_url
```

where `badge.fb_url` contains og-tags.
Everything works fine at the moment.

But when I enable July 2013 migration, I start getting errors

```
A post action for this object already exists.,
code :1611231
```

Seems to be the case of deprecated feature "Duplicate creation actions for the same Open Graph object", BUT in the settings of Badge Object on Advanced tab I don't have any field called "Create action", instead I have "Subscribe action", with a **single** action name there:

*Subscribe Action: earn*

What's wrong?

Comment: I can't help but I can confirm having the same issue. Hopefully someone can chime in. Investigation is ongoing.

Comment: @kain: have you got any luck with this problem? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Hi, @Abhi. I opened a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/644640515561606 and got an answer that this is by design. You will have to create new object each time.